# How to import legacy requirement IDs into TFS 2013?

Tags: tfs, requirements

I am trying to import some existing requirements into TFS 2013 (currently just maintained in a Word doc). However, I need to preserve the existing, pre-assigned requirement IDs (for tracking against existing test cases outside of TFS, etc.). I've come up with multiple ways of doing it:

1. Keep it as part of the requirement title
2. Add it to the description for the requirement
3. Add a tag with the legacy req id to the appropriate req in TFS
4. Add a new field for it to the requirement template (or simply use an existing unused field)

All of these seem pretty unclean to me except the "new field" option, but I'd rather avoid changing the work item template if I could.

Are there are other/better ways to do this? Has anybody done something similar before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually add a field to most of my work items called External ID that I use for this purpose.  It's also useful to link TFS Work Items to say a ticket ID in a Help Desk ticketing system.

Comment: After some more thinking, I am more of this idea. It makes it a little more flexible for other use (as you say), and also makes queries based on the field a little more specific than querying in tags which could contain just about anything. Thanks!